# Equal and round robin distribution of Leads

Tags: leads

I want to create an automated process for Lead Distribution that takes into account the fair dividing of Leads per Lead Source among agents taking into account agent availability like out of office. I have tried exploring omni channel for managing the availability of agents and round robin assignment for allocation of leads , but I am not able to find a way to do the equal distribution  of different types of leads.

Consider the following scenario for example.

There are :
6 leads of type A
10 Leads of type B
4 leads of type C

There are :

3 agents in a team

I want to be able to assign each agentwith 2 leads of type A, 3 Leads of Type B and 1 Leads of type C and plus the remaining leads on a round robin basis.

Is there any better ways of achieving this?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd look into Lead Assignment apps (both paid and free) on the AppExchange before building this yourself. https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxSearchKeywordResults?keywords=Lead%20assignment

Comment: You'd need to tell us more about the queue structure you expect to use. When you say you have 3 agents/team, are you saying that you have 3 agents in your queue? Would all of your different types of Leads be considered by Omni-Channel as Cases or would they be Leads? Without using skill-based routing, this could be very difficult to do with typical queues if sending these from a single Lead Queue. If the work effort for a type lead is different, you'd want to take that into account, using Agent Capacity and defining unique Work Item settings for the different RecordTypes.

Comment: **For anyone else** with the same question, like Mark said, an AppExchange tool for this should be the first port of call.  This app does 100% of what is outlined above: [SuperRoundRobin](http://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FR4MkUAL)